# discord.py code stopping once a class is called

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to run this code

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import classes.orders

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '~')  

def read_token():
    with open(r"D:\documents\discord bots\discord bot py\order bot\order bot\order-bot\token.txt","r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        return lines[0].strip()
    
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(client.latency*1000)}ms')

@client.command()
async def order(ctx,element,number):
    member=ctx.author
    member = str(member)
    await ctx.send('order has been placed')
    print(f'ran {member}')
    new_order=Order(element,number)
    await ctx.send('order has been placed')
    number=newOrder.number      

for filename in os.listdir(r'D:\documents\discord bots\discord bot py\order bot\order bot\order-bot\cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

token=read_token()

client.run(token)
```

orders.py

```
class Order:

    def _init_(self,element,number):
        print('ran')
        self.element=element
        self.number=number
        print('ran')
```

when I try to run this and call the order command, the bot sends the first message and the first print works, but it does not run anything within the order class *init* function or anything after creating the new instance of class order, ie the other 'order has been placed' message. no errors are thrown, and if I call any other command they still work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you importing your 'Order' class ?
Do you still have your problem if you use this :

```
from classes.orders import Order
```

Comment: it still has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I only had one underscore on each side of the class init function.